# The logo is not appearing on my website header(Astra)

Tags: themes, logo

I have created a website on WordPress using the Astra theme.

When I want to change the logo for my website it shows the older one, then I have removed the old logo file from the media as well.
Now the logo does not appear on the website.

Would you please help me out with this issue?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to WPSE. Discussion on Third-party themes/plugins are considered off-topic here. You'll get better help on the official support channel though.

Comment: I had the same issue in the past and have it again now. I then somehow managed to get the logo to show, but I don't remember what the trick was... :-(
As soon as I got it done, I'll write you back. Let's see who's faster.
Kind regards,
L